# jqGrid : Add new Row Button

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I want to create a html button element. When someone will click on the button then a new window for adding new record will be opened. That means, the button will do the task of the footer toolbar add icon .

Comment: Do u want to a pop-up window by clicking the button??

Comment: yes. the popup window which appears when i click on the add new row  toolbar icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you have enabled **pager** for the **jqGrid** it by default provide options for adding new row in the pager, For which just add the property,

```
pager: '#pcrud',
```

and after the jqGrid definition add following line,

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pcrud',{});
```

Now, Moving onto your question as you have asked to create separate button for opening add item popup, Create a button

```
<button class="add-new-row">Add New Row</button>
```

And , Add jqGrid popup trigger code on button click event

```
 $(".add-new-row").on("click",function(){
        $("#grid").editGridRow( "new" );
   });
```

You can follow the following documentation for better understanding [Form Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) , [jqGrid Pager](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:pager) and [Inline Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing).

And if you want to add inline row in the jqGrid use it instead,

```
$(".add-new-row").on("click",function(){
    $("#grid").jqGrid('addRow',"new");
});
```

### And here is the [working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jqJch/69/) for you.

P.S Go thought the docuemntaion once so you can mold it to as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

```
html:
<p class="back-screen"></p>
<p class="front-screen"><a href="">&times;</a></p>
<button id="show" type='button'>Modal</button>

css:
.back-screen{position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);z-index: -1; display:none;}
.front-screen{position: absolute; top:25%; left:25%; background: #fff; width: 50%;height:50%; z-index:100;display:none;}
.active{display:inline}

jquery:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#show').click(function(){
          $('.back-screen,.front-screen').fadeIn(500).addClass('active');
    })
})

demo: <http://jsfiddle.net/wahidsherief/8u2y9ddw/1/>
```

Comment: See the subject line of the question - "jqGrid : Add new Row Button" . I need the same functionality of jqGrid add new row button.